# Get current location/url of iframe and assign into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, dom, iframe

I have some content hosted on my own servers which I'm displaying to the user dynamically. However the content is a few layers deep and I need the url/location of the iframe so I can assign it to a link.

The result should be when a user clicks on the link, it takes them to the page with the iframe as well as displaying the proper page/layer within the iframe.

How do I achieve this via javascript or jquery? Or is xpath also required for this? If you disagree, please don't downvote this question but explain why I shouldn't post it since too many downvotes and you get banned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `jquery` for this, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#iframeid").load(function(){
      alert(this.contentWindow.location);// do what you want with this location
    });
});
```

**Note:** First add a latest version of jquery

Comment: Check that you have added `jquery` before using it, also check `id` of your `iframe`. then test. or try `alert( $('iframeId').contents().get(0).location.href );`. Is there any `error` comes?

Comment: I use this but i ger error "Permission denied to access property 'href'"